# Lisp and clojure code fail at Google KickStart competition retype problem

Tags: python, clojure, common-lisp, sbcl

I was trying google KickStart competition for year 2020 in different programing languages but my common lisp(sbcl) and clojure code fail at google test but both of them working properly on my local machine, any idea about what I'm doing wrong?
**Working python code looks like this:**

```
def short_path(n,k,s):
    return min((k + n),(2*k - 2*s + n))

for i in range (1,int(input())+1):
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(i,short_path(*[int(z) for z in input().split()])))
```

**Lisp(sbcl) version:**

```
(defun short_path (n k s)
  (let (x y)
    (setf x (+ n k))
    (setf y (+ (- (* k 2) (* 2 s)) n))
    (if (< x y) x y)))
(defun main ()
  (loop for i from 1 to (read)
     do (format t "Case #~a: ~a~%" i (short_path (read) (read) (read)))))
```

**Clojure version:**

```
(defn short_path [n k s]
  (min (+ n k) (+ n (- (* 2 k) (* 2 s)))))
(defn main []
  (dotimes [i (read)] (println (str "Case #" (+ i 1) ": " (short_path (read) (read) (read))))))
```

**Edited:**
For testing we should use:

```
cat Sample.in | python retype.py
cat Sample.in | sbcl --script retype.lisp
cat Sample.in | clj retype.clj
```

**Sample.in :**

```
6
10 5 2
10 7 6
10 5 5
10 6 5
3 2 1
100 40 30
```

Comment: "fail at google test" - what does that mean? Please add the errors, stacktraces, ... you get.

Comment: @cfrick google kickstart is a website for competition it does not give you those things, It just throw : "Sample Failed: WA" anyway I add extra lines for how to test the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Google Kick Start platform notes for Clojure](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/faq#platform), the test runner is expecting to run a script rather than a `-main` function. I haven't signed up to Google Kick Start, but this should work:

```clj
(defn min-path [n k s]
  (+ n (min k (* 2 (- k s)))))

(dotimes [i (read)]
  (println (str "Case #" (inc i) ": " (min-path (read) (read) (read)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I read the FAQ coding part only :) .  you are PRECISE man. your answer has two point for me : 1) read all the doc first 2) factor out mathematical expression before writing a code :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the purpose of your code is but the use of `let` looks odd to me. Better try:

```
(defun short_path (n k s)
   (let ((x (+ n k))
         (y (+ (- (* k 2) (* 2 s)) n) ))
     (if (< x y) x y)))

CL-USER> (short_path 1 2 3)
-1
CL-USER> (short_path 3 2 1)
5
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I changed the let part, But my problem was the main function. I removed the defun main and made it like script.